# How to create 'smart' nested rule for css using webpack and vue

Tags: css, sass, webpack, vue.js, vue-component

I don't know how to better name this topic 
but idea is the following. I want to show different color for a component depends on a parent class. 
for this project I use webpack, vue, vue-loader, sass.

I have a sass file this file contents all settings for pages what color should use for specific page

```
    $colors: ".page-home" blue, ".page-about" green;

    @each $i in $colors {
       $page: nth($i, 1);
       $color: nth($i, 2);

      #{$page} .component_1, .component_2, .component_n {
        color: $color;
      }
   }
```

I have a component is written as vue component

```
@import "colors"; 
.compoent_1 {
  border:1px solid black
}
```

A issue is I have a lot of components and it very difficult to support the colors file in consistency. When I want to add a new component or remove an old one I always have to go to this file and edit it is annoying me

So how I see the solution is create a main file.

```
.page-home:blue;
.page-about: green;
```

I'd like write components in the following style

```
.component {
  border:1px solid black;
  color: $PAGE_COLOR;
}
```

and this code should generate

```
.page-home .component_1, .component_2, .component_n {
  color: blue;
 }
.page-about .component_1, .component_2, .component_n {
 color: green;
 }
```

thats all. thanks for any suggestion